# Electron win.flashFrame() method when app is minimized

Tags: windows, electron

`win.flashFrame()` makes tray icon flash until the icon is clicked and the app window is back in the focus again (on Windows 10)

However, if the app is minimized, the flashing ends automatically after just a couple of seconds without even clicking on the icon.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

If the window is minimized the user won't see the window flash, you will need to use the [`win.setProgressBar`](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#winsetprogressbarprogress-options) funciton. This will make a loading bar behind the icon in the tray, you can also set the mode of the progress bar to `indeterminate` and set the progress to `100%` and it will flash yellow/orange. This is a general standard used by lots of applications to get a users attention when the app is minimized.

```
win.setProgressBar(1, {
    mode: "indeterminate"
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work in window 11,  electron version: 23.2.4.