# Electron's flashFrame(true) doesn't flash taskbar icon continuously

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

***tl;dr*** :

**Expected behavior:**

`flashFrame(true)` to continuously flash until `flashFrame(false)` being called.

**Actual behavior:**

`flashFrame(true)` only flash for 4 times.

**My question:**

Is there any configuration I need to configure in `BrowserWindow()` or it is expected?

---

**Context:**

I'm currently working on a ReactJS **messaging desktop application** where I wish the taskbar icon to flash when the application receive a new message and when the window is minimized. I did perform some searches on the internet and on the [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winflashframeflag) documentation before I ask this question over here. I do manage to find someone to have similar question asked over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45504387/electron-win-flashframe-method-when-app-is-minimized) but the answer isn't what I wanted to achieve.

What I've observed, the `flashFrame(true)` is indeed working but it only flash for precisely 4 times before it went  back to default mode. My code is as below:

```
if (electron) { //if it is run on Electron
  if (remote.getCurrentWindow().isMinimized() === true) { //if the current window are minimized
      remote.getCurrentWindow().flashFrame(true);
   }
}
```

Is there any configuration I need to make for the `flashFrame(true)` to flash continuously or is it Electron expected behavior?

**Environment:**

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "latest",
    "electron-builder": "latest",
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hardcoded in chromium's codebase https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:ui/views/win/hwnd_message_handler.cc;l=820?q=FlashWindow&ss=chromium to flash 4 times.

```
fwi.uCount = 4;
```

So this is expected behavior cannot be configured.